# Plot Pixel of Hex Buffer

Tags: c, image, operating-system, buffer

I have a Hex Code of an Image

```
static unsigned char Wallpaper[] = {
0xD9, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xD9, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 
0xD9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x99, 0xD9, 0x05, 0x05, 0x02, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 
0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, /* skipped */
```

RGBAtoHex function :

```
unsigned long RGBAtoHex(int r, int g, int b, int a)
{
    return ((a & 0xff) << 24) + ((r & 0xff) << 16) + ((g & 0xff) << 8) + (b & 0xff);
}
```

`PlotPixel(x, y, hex /* 0xAARRGGBB */)` function is surely right.

```
PlotPixel(x, y, colour)
{
*(uint32_t*)((uint64_t)TargetFramebuffer->BaseAddress + (x*4) + (y * TargetFramebuffer->PixelsPerScanLine * 4)) = colour;
}
```

```
void PlotPic()
{
    uint32_t pos;

    for (int y = 0; y < TargetFramebuffer->Height; y++)
    {
        
        for (int x = 0; x < TargetFramebuffer->Width; x++)
        {
             int r = Wallpaper[pos++];
             int g = Wallpaper[pos++];
             int b = Wallpaper[pos++];
             int a = Wallpaper[pos++];

             unsigned int pixel = RGBAtoHex(r, g, b, a);

             PlotPixel(x, y, pixel);
         }
     }
}
```

I am tried to Plot the Pixels of this buffer with the Above code but failed, Output is : [image]

**So How can I get Right Pixels?**

Note : I am using Graphics Output Protocol offered by UEFI Protocols.

Comment: `uint32_t pos; ... int r = Wallpaper[pos++];` The code has Undefined Behaviour because `pos` is not initialised.

Comment: @kaylum ```uint32_t pos = 0;``` , But problem not Fixed (Same)

Comment: Have you done any debugging of the code? For example, have you run the program in a debugger or even used basic debug print statements to verify that the pixel values returned from the `RGBAtoHex` are correct?

Comment: Then your `PlotPixel` is wrong. You can't claim that both are correct and yet get the wrong result. Or you are not showing us some code that matters. We really can't help with this incomplete info. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I thinks RGBAtoHex is Wrong,

Comment: @kaylum See the PlotPixel function in Question

Comment: "Hex Code of an Image" What does "image" mean? Where did you get that hexdump? Is it content of some bmp/png/jpg/gif file?

Comment: @Gerhardh jpg format

Comment: That is plain file content? Are you aware that there are headers in picture files that are located before the pixel data starts. And that you need to decompress Jpg to get pixel data at all?

Comment: I am used this for converting that image to hex dump https://github.com/bitbank2/image_to_c

Comment: @Gerhardh I am also tried to load an BMP image I am also readen headers of that , but same problem comes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692110/reading-and-plotting-bmp-image-in-c-from-scratch)

Comment: If the frame buffer has a stride (=distance in bytes from pixel 0 of row n to pixel 0 of row (n+1)) that is different from the visible width, the address calculation would fail.